# Set button:before to dimensions of button in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm messing around with CSS animations with pseudo elements for the first time.

I have a button that I want a ripple effect on click, without javascript. I'm almost there, but my button's ':before' element keeps setting itself to the width of the container rather than the width of the button.

Is there any way that I can set the dimensions of the buttons ':before' to the dimensions of the button without JavaScript? Also, I'm having trouble with the actual positioning of the :before element, ideally I would like it to perfectly overlap with the button's border. So any advice with that would help a lot!

Here's the codepen (uses sass): https://codepen.io/NotDan/pen/qvKvQv

- the effect is working the way I want it to, it's just the alignment and sizing of the :before element that I need help with

Here's the css:

```
.custom-btn-primary {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #d98324;
    border: 2px solid #d98324;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.custom-btn-primary:hover {
    color: #e5a864;
    border: 2px solid #e5a864;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.custom-btn-primary:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 2px solid #d98324;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.custom-btn-primary:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: #d98324;
    color: #230007;
    font-size: calc(1em + 2px);
    border: 0;
}
.custom-btn-primary:focus:before {
    animation: ripple-out 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <button class="custom-btn-primary">primary</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <button class="custom-btn-secondary">secondary</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <button class="custom-btn-light">light</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with your codepen and found that you just need to add `position: relative;` to your `.custom-btn-#{$color}` class.

Your `:before` pseudo element is already `position: absolute` but it’s currently positioning itself to the column instead of the button itself.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't think one line would fix it! thanks for the fast response